# Changing the interval of the SNMP Interface Data Graphs

Tags: opennms

I am trying to change the interval that appears in the snmp interface data graphs in opennms  from 5 mins to 30 second. I have ajusted the poller-configuration, datacollection configuration and the collectd configuration but it still only shows 5 mins in the graph

What am i missing

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece is to adjust the `step` value on the `<rrd>` element at the top of `datacollection-config.xml` to 30 (this one is in whole seconds rather than milliseconds). After doing this, and with OpenNMS stopped, you must delete all the existing RRD / JRB files in your `OPENNMS_HOME/share/rrd/snmp` directory. They will be recreated on the next collection cycle following startup and start filling with 30-second samples.

Your changes to `poller-configuration.xml` will have no effect on data collection, so you might as well roll them back. The data produced by the poller is strictly about response time.

Note that if you're using Newts to store time-series data in a Cassandra cluster, the required changes differ. I assume you're not since you didn't specify and RRDTool / JRobin is the default.